# Происходит снос строки ul списка

Tags: css

У меня есть ul список который должен по скроллу прокручиваться, но в li списках полностью предложение не помещается. Мне нужно сделать так, что бы в li все поместилось в одну строку и не сносилось, поставить .item ширину не получится потому что где-то будет ширина большая.

```css
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .wrapper {
      width: 450px;
      background-color: #ccc;
      height: 700px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .list {
      display: flex;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    .item {
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 10px 5px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="item">МЕДЬ TECU | KME</li>
      <li class="item">222</li>
      <li class="item">АЛЮМИНИЙ Reynolux | ARCONIC</li>
      <li class="item">444</li>
      <li class="item">HPL-панели PARKLEX</li>
      <li class="item">666</li>
      <li class="item">777</li>
      <li class="item">888</li>
      <li class="item">999</li>
      <li class="item">000</li>
      <li class="item">111</li>
      <li class="item">222</li>
      <li class="item">333</li>
      <li class="item">444</li>
      <li class="item">Комплектующие для монтажа</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```css
 * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .wrapper {
        width: 450px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        height: 700px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .scroll {
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }

    .list {
        display: flex;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
        width: 1500px;
    }

    .item {
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 10px 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="scroll">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="item">МЕДЬ TECU | KME</li>
                <li class="item">222</li>
                <li class="item">АЛЮМИНИЙ Reynolux | ARCONIC</li>
                <li class="item">444</li>
                <li class="item">HPL-панели PARKLEX</li>
                <li class="item">666</li>
                <li class="item">777</li>
                <li class="item">888</li>
                <li class="item">999</li>
                <li class="item">000</li>
                <li class="item">111</li>
                <li class="item">222</li>
                <li class="item">333</li>
                <li class="item">444</li>
                <li class="item">Комплектующие для монтажа</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```